# Keeping uilabel size and font size constant while shrinking the parent uiview

Tags: ios, user-interface, user-controls, uilabel, uigesturerecognizer

I am implementing an app with a trackbar which itself is a view and it needs to display the minimum and maximum values (of the variable which is associated with the bar) so I have added two labels to the top left and top right of it. Think of something like this without an enabled slider:

[image: http://tdwiki.daverabelink.net/images/4/42/TrackbarSample.jpg]

I would like to be able to shrink or magnify this view with pinch gesture and the below code does work fine :

```
-(void) handlePinch:(UIPinchGestureRecognizer *)gr
{
    //Shrinking
    if(gr.scale < 1)
    {
        //Get screen width
        CGFloat screenWidth = [UIScreen mainScreen].bounds.size.width;
        //If the view's would be size is smaller than half the screen's size then don't do anything
        //Otherwise shrink the view
        if(self.frame.size.width * gr.scale >= screenWidth / 2)
        {
            //Only scale on x axis, y axes stays the same
            self.transform = CGAffineTransformScale(self.transform, gr.scale, 1);
        }

    }
    //Magnifying
    else if (gr.scale > 1) 
    {
        //Only scale on x axis, y axes stays the same
        self.transform = CGAffineTransformScale(self.transform, gr.scale, 1);
    }

    //Set scale amount back to 1
    gr.scale = 1;
}
```

The problem is when the view is shrank the labels on top left and right are also shrank and their font size gets smaller. Since I scale the view only horizontally this looks bizarre. I want to set the labels' size constant and shrink everything else inside the view.

I have tried to assign a new frame rectangle with the original labels' sizes after shrinking but it didn't work.Do you have any tips?

edit : Setting minimumFontSize property did not work either (I don't try minimumScaleFactor because I'm still using ios 5 sdk)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution in separating my trackbar from the view that shall support pinch gesture. It was bad design to include trackbar in it beforehand, check your ui design before putting effort on more complicated stuff.

Answer (score 0):

I think this behavior is actually controlled by the view you have your label on - it's not controlled by the label itself.  There is a autoresizesSubviews property of UIView that defaults to YES, and that makes anything inside a view shrink when the UIView shrinks.  Since your pinch gesture is actually attached to the view behind the label and not the label itself, your pinch is shrinking the view, then the view shrinks the label.  Try setting autoresizesSubviews = NO, and let me know if that works for you.

Comment: what you said came to my mind also but i have many other views and controls inside the same view which should be resized. I only want to keep these 2 labels at fixed size. so tomorrow i will expand them as categories and override their resizeWithOldSuperviewSize method i believe it should work then, but now it is sleep time :)